# Python Sierpinski Triangle Using Class Point

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to draw a Sierpinski Triangle using a class point, but when I try to run the program I made it won't let me draw the triangle. We have to have an input function for the length of the three sides of the big triangle(L) and the number of iterations(I).Help please! Here's what I have.

```
import turtle

class point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def midpoint(self, p2):
        return point((self.x + p2.x) / 2, (self.y + p2.y) / 2)

def DrawSierpinskiTriangle(length, iterations):
    turn = 0
    angle = 60
    # Initialize the turtle
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turle.penup()
    turtle.degrees()
    # Starting point on the cancas
    midpoint = ((self.x + p2.x) / 2, (self.y + p2.y) / 2)
    decode = {'-':Left, '+':Right, 'X':Forward, 'H':Forward}
    code = 'H--X--X'
    # Start the drawing
    turtle.goto(point[0], point[1])
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turt=turtle.getpen()
    startposition=turt.clone()
    # Get triangle
    path = code
    length = x
    for i in range(0,length):
        path = path.replace('X','XX')
        path = path.replace('H','H--X++H++X--H')
    for i in path:
        [turn, point, fwd, angle, turt]=decode[i](turn, point, fwd, angle, turt)

def main():
    input("Enter the length of the triangle: ")
    input("Enter the number of iterations: ")

main()
```

Comment: You might want to specify more details of your program, like that you are using the Python `turtle` library to draw the triangle. Have you properly imported the `turtle` library? Also, can you describe the errors you are having with your code in greater detail?

Answer (score 1):

A) You probably want to use [raw_input](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=input#raw_input), if using python 2.x

B) You're not saving the inputted values. I.e.

```
tLength = input("Enter the length of the triangle: ")
```

C) You never call `DrawSierpinskiTriangle`

In summary, try the below, and that should get you back on track and you can begin debugging your Sierpinski function

```
def main():
    tLength = input("Enter the length of the triangle: ")
    numIter = input("Enter the number of iterations: ")
    DrawSierpinskiTriangle(tLength, numIter)

main()
```

Comment: `raw_input`  vs. `input` depends on what Python version he is using.

Comment: @SteinarLima indeed, but it has since been edited to show python 3.x tag, answer updated